# python 3.3 socket relay, server can't access value

Tags: string, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python.  One of the main things I'm trying to do is create a relay that will relay sockets sent from one client to another.   As I'm beginning this, I've started doing some simple modifications to a basic client/server sample script.  However, what occurs is that the server itself will not or for some reason cannot print out the value that it is repeating back to the client.  I only get "Recieved ''" like it's an empty string.  Please help me understand and fix this?

## server program

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
data = ''
message = ''
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
data = conn.recv(1024)
if not data: break
conn.sendall(data)

conn.close()
print('Received', repr(data.decode()))
```

## client program

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.56.1'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
x = input('Message:')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(x.encode())
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received', repr(data.decode()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good job, Stack Overflow.  Now I at least know where I'm not going to find help.  That is in itself helpful in some way.  The one question that doesn't get deleted goes unanswered for days.  lol.  If anybody happens to stumble across this thread having this or a similar issue before some presumptuous, self-important chutzpah who probably enjoys the sweet, sweet smell of their own believed to be flawless fart deletes it, I suggest you find a real forum.